# About unsynchronized & synchronized access in Java Collections Framework?

Tags: java

Can anyone explain what is unsynchronized & synchronized access in Java Collections Framework?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Synchronized vs unsynchronized access doesn't have to do with the Java Collections Framework per see.

Synchronized access means that you have some **sort of locking** for accessing the data. This can be introduced by using the `synchronized` keyword or by using some of the higher level constructs from the `java.util.concurrent` package.

Unsynchronized access means that you *don't* have any locking involved when accessing the data.

If you're using a collection in several threads, you better make sure that you're accessing it in a synchronized way, or, that the collection itself is [thread safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), i.e., takes care of such locking internally.

To make sure all accesses to some collection `coll` is accessed in a synchronized way, you can either

- ...surround accesses with `synchronized (coll) { ... }`

  ```
  public void someMethod() {
      synchronized (coll) {
           // do work...
      }
  }
  ```
- ...encapsulate it using [`Collections.synchronizedCollections`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedCollection%28java.util.Collection%29)

  ```
  coll = Collections.synchronizedCollection(coll);
  ```

In the former approach, you need to make sure that *every access* to the collection is covered by `synchronized`. In the latter approach, you need to make sure that *every reference* points at the synchronized version of the collection.

As pointed out by @Fatal however, you should understand that the latter approach only transforms a thread unsafe collection into a thread safe collection. This is most often not sufficient for making sure that the class *you* are writing is thread safe. For an example, see @Fatals comment.

Comment: Good answer but in my opinion you should mention a very common error done when dealing with synchronized collections: Having a synchronized collection does not mean that you do not have to care about synchronization when dealing with it.

i.e. `for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) { list.get(i) }` may throw NPE even with a synchronized list when accessed by concurrent threads and not externally synchronized.

Answer (score 5):

Synchronized access means it is [thread-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). So different threads can access the collection concurrently without any problems, but it is probably a little bit slower depending on what you are doing.

Unsynchronized is the opposite. Not thread-safe, but a little bit faster.

Comment: Synchronized operations consumes more time compared to non-synchronized ones so if there is no need for thread safe operation, Array List is a better choice as performance will be improved because of the concurrent processes.

Answer (score 1):

The synchronized access in Java Collection Framework is normally done by wrapping with `Collections.synchronizedCollection(...)` etc. and only access through this wrapper.

There are some exceptions already synchronized like `Hashtable` and `Vector`.

But keep in mind:
Synchronization is done over the collection instance itself and has a scope for each method call. So subsequent calls maybe interrupted by another thread.

Example:
You first call `isEmtpy()` method getting result that it is not empty and after that you want to retrieve an element from that collection. But this second method call may fail, because collection may be empty now due to actions by another thread done between your calls.

So even with synchronized collections you've to care about synchronization and it maybe necessary to synchronize yourself outside the collection!